# How can I update a cached list where other threads retain the old cache list

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a cached list of users in my app. A couple of the admin pages need the list of all users (the total is small enough this isn't a problem).

The approach I am taking is:

1. When the cached list is requested, that list will not change.
2. When a user is CrUD, there is a call to add them to the cache.
3. When that call is made, the existing list is copied into the new list and the CrUD user is added/updated/removed from the list. And that list is then the new cached list.

Great idea. But I just wrote some unit tests that are performing this and it doesn't work. Because 2 threads are rebuilding the list and the one that writes it second, wins. I can put a `lock (this)` around the rebuilding of the list and that works great.

But that is a terrible approach. Great for identifying the problem but not good in production.

In normal use, this approach of any list returned is immutable works great. How can I accomplish this without a `lock`?

In C# but this is a language agnostic question, although there may be some C# class, etc. that makes this an easy solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I accomplish this without a `lock`?

You can't. At least not if you want to stick with a `List<T>` that contains mutable `User` objects. The `List<T>` collection is not thread-safe. Even if it was, mutating the `User` elements it contains without synchronization would result in buggy/undefined behavior.

> I can put a `lock (this)` around the rebuilding of the list and that works great. But that is a terrible approach.

Not necessarily. If you make careful use of the [`lock`](https://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_When_to_Lock) statement, meaning that you protect only the interaction with the shared state (the list and the users) and not the rebuilding of the new list before it becomes shared, the [contention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.lockcontentioncount) is likely to be minimal and the performance quite decent.

Of course there are other options available, that don't involve a shared `List<T>`. For example:

1. [`ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2) updated with `GetOrAdd`/`AddOrUpdate`.
2. [`ImmutableList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1) updated with [`ImmutableInterlocked.Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutableinterlocked.update).

Both of these low-lock alternatives require that the `User` type must be immutable. Not only they'll perform better (most likely), but they'll also be more convenient too.

---

Example with a `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` and [`record class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) as `User`:

```
// Record classes are immutable by default
public record class User(int Id, string Name, int Reputation);

private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, User> _users = new();

// Add a new user with 10 reputation,
// or increment the reputation of an existing user by 10.
public User ReputationIncrement(int id, string userName)
{
    return _users.AddOrUpdate(id,
        key => new User(key, userName, 10),
        (key, existing) => existing with { Reputation = existing.Reputation + 10 });
}
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TouleV).

Comment: All good points. The user objects are very mutable which is a big restriction. However, your point that lock if used judiciously is very good. I think I was giving in to that common vice - premature optimization. I'll go with lock and look for something else if this ends up being slow. thank you

Comment: @DavidThielen when you say that the user objects are very mutable, how many times is each one of them updated per second on average?

Comment: I'm estimating future number of users and the actions they take. But likely 1 - 10/minute. On the flip side, those cached lists will be accessed (usually getting a subset) 10 - 100/second.

Comment: @DavidThielen 10 updates per minute is nothing to worry about. I edited the question and added an example with immutable `User` type.

Comment: Thank you. A record won't work for me but it's an excellent suggestion in your answer.